# SQL - How To Return A Result Without Multiples

Tags: sql-server, business-objects

I am trying to write a Business Object report to show a list of the people who have not returned a timesheet on a selected date, but I can't figure out how to stop the SQL query returning multiple entries for individuals.

My Staff_Table contains 2 columns - Employee No & Name
My Timesheet_Table contains, among other things, Employee No & Week_Ending_Date.

I can easily write a statement to return all users who have entered a timesheet with a Week_Ending_Date of e.g. 10/08/2012.  However, if I try to return a list of all those who have not enetered a timesheet for 10/08/2012, I pick up every single timesheet in the table which does not have that date, so, for example, if a person has submitted 100 timesheets and only 1 of them is for 10/08/2012, the results will show him 99 times.
What I need is a fixed list of everyone on the Staff_Table who has not submitted for that date, showing once only.

I tried a Union with NOT EXISTS but either I'm doing it wrong or it simply isn't appropriate.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Including your query would help at this point

Comment: I used DISTINCT but it didn't help me here.

Comment: I know, I'll have to work on diluting the query a little before posting.  It was auto generated by Business Objects and contains all manner of joins etc.  I'll need to filter it down to post to keep it consistent with my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding DISTINCT to your query

ie

```
SELECT DISTINCT ...
```

Your query should look something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM Staff
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    Select EmployeeNo 
    from Timesheet 
    where WeekEndingDate='2012-08-10'     
    and TimeSheet.EmployeeNo  = Staff.EmployeeNo 
)
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM Staff
WHERE EmployeeNo NOT IN 
(
    Select EmployeeNo 
    from Timesheet 
    where WeekEndingDate='2012-08-10'
)
```

Comment: Should have mentioned, I tried that and it don't alter my results.

Comment: Thanks Podiluska and everyone.  Using the NOT IN command here did the trick.  Another lesson learned.  Thank you.

Comment: Podiluska posted the `not in` after kingkong0924, who deserves the credit imho

Answer (score 2):

You should select all employee numbers that do not enter timesheet first. Then, filter the list using NOT IN.

```
DECLARE @Week_Ending_Date DATETIME = '2012-08-10'
DECLARE @Staff TABLE
(
    EmployeeNo INT NOT NULL,
    EmployeeName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)
DECLARE @TimeSheet TABLE
(
    EmployeeNo INT NOT NULL,
    Week_Ending_Date DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @Staff (EmployeeNo, EmployeeName)
VALUES (1, 'Alan'), (2, 'Peter')

INSERT INTO @TimeSheet (EmployeeNo, Week_Ending_Date)
VALUES (1, '2012-08-10'), (1, '2012-08-17'), (2, '2012-08-03')

SELECT
    S.EmployeeName
FROM
    @Staff S
WHERE
    EmployeeNo NOT IN (SELECT EmployeeNo FROM @TimeSheet WHERE Week_Ending_Date = @Week_Ending_Date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `not exists` clause to find staff that has not submitted a particular timesheet:

```
select  *
from    Staff s
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    Timesheet t
        where   t.EmployeeNo =  s.EmployeeNo
                and t.Week_Ending_Date = '2012-08-19'
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just select all employees who haven't submitted a timesheet and group the results by their name?

```
select Name
from Staff_Table
left join Timesheet_Table on Staff_Table.[Employee No] = Timesheet_Table.[Employee No] and  Timesheet_Table.Week_Ending_Date = '10 August 2012'
having Timesheet_Table.Week_Ending_Date is null
group by Name, Timesheet_Table.Week_Ending_Date
```

I haven't tested this, but something along these lines.

Comment: You can't use unaggregated columns in a `having` clause